# AWS Kinesis Data Stream + API Gateway Integration | Retry

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

While using an API Gateway as a proxy for Kinesis Data Stream. Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html

I am concerned about "ProvisionedThroughputExceeded" exception of Kinesis, which is thrown when the data written/read is more than the provisioned capacity with Shards.

I wanna know, what kind of error/retry handling is happening at the API Gateway. I have not been able to find anything solid, like how many retries the API Gateway does, does API Gateway uses exponential backoff, etc?

Here is what I have discovered so far:

- API Gateway supports Retries: ["Each AWS SDK supporting Amazon API Gateway implements automatic retry logic"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/handling-errors/)
- Kinesis Data Streams also support retry: ["the maximum amount of retries to attempt with a request. See AWS.Kinesis.maxRetries for more information."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html)

I tried searching "AWS.Kinesis.maxRetries" on Google and AWS Docs page, but got nothing. Can someone help me find more resources on the above?

Also, I am not sure if my interpretation of the API Gateway resource above is correct. Can someone please confirm?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any information? Thanks

Comment: No, dude, I couldn't get any info on the above. So, I implemented retry at my end.

Comment: Did you try to set your kinesis stream "on_demand" ?

Comment: Yes @ThomasP1988, but I still get the mentioned issue occasionally, that is, when the demand increases a lot in short span of time.